# Multithreading to download data from a website

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I'm doing an app which downloads info via a request to a website, giving me back and HTML and parsing this data I obtain my app info. For downloading this data I'm using, using a url with all the parameters the request needs at the end.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSString* htmlString;
htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
[self parserHTML:htmlString];  // here I fill a NSArray with the info parsed
[self searchSomething:htmlString];  // continue filling the NSArray

...
```

The task for download the data and parser the HTML takes long time.

What can I do to make this faster? Grand Central Dispatch? If so, how can I use it, because I'm using this and it doesn't works, because the NSSArray is empty:

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("pharmacy downloader", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{ 
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlReal];

    NSString* htmlString;
    htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    [self parserHTML:htmlString];  // here I fill a NSArray with the info parsed
    [self searchSomething:htmlString];  // continue filling the NSArray
});
dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
```

If I don't use GCD it works. What can be the problem??

Thanks for your help. I'm totally lost!!! :S

Comment: Where do you define the array, you are filling during the parsing? Is this a property of the object? Maybe the parsing is not done at the time, you access the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use [NSURLDownload](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLDownload_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead.

For some sample code you may take a look at [QuickLookDownloader](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/QuickLookDownloader/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009082)